# Arm crosscompiling error, libdaemon.h no such file or directory

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, configure

I'm trying to cross-compile some C++ project for an arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi processor,I have set the ./configure of this project in the following way:

```
./configure --build=i686-linux --host=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi CC=~/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=~/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++ LD=~/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-ld LDFLAGS=-L/usr/include/libdaemon --with-sysroot=/home/thales/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/justInstalled --disable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-long-long --enable-target-optspace --disable-nls --with-float=soft --disable-multilib --enable-symvers=gn
```

The configuration succeeded, however when I do make I got an inclusion error

```
libtool: link: warning: library `/home/j/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/lib/libstdc++.la' was moved.
  CXX    Main.o
Main.cpp:28:30: error: libdaemon/daemon.h: No such file or directory
Main.cpp: In function 'int __daemon_run()':
Main.cpp:175: error: 'daemon_retval_send' was not declared in this scope
.
.
.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/j/ibrdtn-svn/daemon'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

If I go to the file Main.cpp to see what is going on, it's complains of the include of libdeamon

```
...
#include "config.h"
#include "Configuration.h"
#include <ibrcommon/Logger.h>
#include <ibrcommon/data/File.h>

#ifdef HAVE_LIBDAEMON
#include <libdaemon/daemon.h>
#endif

#include <string.h>
#include <csignal>
#include <set>
...
```

I've checked out that I have installed the libdeamon

```
@ubuntu:~$ pkg-config --libs libdaemon
-ldaemon
@ubuntu:~$locate libdaemon
/usr/include/libdaemon
/usr/include/libdaemon/daemon.h
/usr/include/libdaemon/dexec.h
/usr/include/libdaemon/dfork.h
/usr/include/libdaemon/dlog.h
/usr/include/libdaemon/dnonblock.h
/usr/include/libdaemon/dpid.h
/usr/include/libdaemon/dsignal.h
/usr/lib/libdaemon.a
/usr/lib/libdaemon.so
/usr/lib/libdaemon.so.0
/usr/lib/libdaemon.so.0.5.0
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libdaemon.pc
```

Why the inclusion is wrong?? I've tried to include using

```
./configure (as before) LDFLAGS=-llibdeamon (as before)
```

But the configure tell me that there's an error, and I have to read the conf.log, which says

```
/home/j/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -llibdeamon
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Regards

EDIT

I have tried to crosscompile the libdaemon library but I cannot achieve it,I've download the libdaemon source [link](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/libdaemon/libdaemon-0.14.tar.gz), after untar it I went to the directory where the code is in and executed  `./configure --build=i686-linux --host=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi CC=~/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=~/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++ LD=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-ld --prefix=/usr`

and finally install the library by doing

```
make install DESTDIR=/home/t/libdaemon-0.14
```

However, when I relaunch the configure of the main project like this

```
./configure --build=i686-linux --host=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi CC=~/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=~/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-g++ LD=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi-ld CCPFLAGS=-I/home/t/libdaemon-0.14/usr/include LDFLAGS=-L/home/t/libdaemon-0.14/lib --with-sysroot=/home/t/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/justInstalled --disable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-long-long --enable-target-optspace --disable-nls --with-float=soft --disable-multilib --enable-symvers=gnu
```

I still get the same error at the beginning of this post... What am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance

EDIT2:

I think I now the problem, libdeamon is not being cross-compiled for the arm, and I cannot understand why, after cross-compiling the library libdeamon I have checked that the library isn't crosscompiled for arm,it's still for the build a intel as it can be seen

```
:~/libdaemon-0.14$ file -F usr/*/*.*
usr/lib/libdaemon.lausr/lib/libdaemon.a       libtool library file, 
usr/lib/libdaemon.sousr/lib/libdaemon.a       symbolic link to `libdaemon.so.0.5.0'
usr/lib/libdaemon.so.0usr/lib/libdaemon.a     symbolic link to `libdaemon.so.0.5.0'
usr/lib/libdaemon.so.0.5.0usr/lib/libdaemon.a ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0xe4959941fb153e1dec5ec84f798dc32928219ae2, not stripped
```

If I try to compile the main project with that "crosscompiled" library I get this

```
libtool: link: warning: library `/home/j/s/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/SW3.2p1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-mv5sft-linux-gnueabi/lib/libstdc++.la' was moved.
/home/j/libdaemon-0.14/usr/lib/libdaemon.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [dtnd] Error 1
```

So what can I do??

Comment: Do you have the arm build of libdaemon? You should build it and pass its path.

Comment: I don't think so.I will need to download the source of libdaemon and crosscompile it for the arm?

Comment: I have already crosscompiled the library(it's explined in the original post) but worthless...

Comment: You need to specify both path (-L) and library name (-l).
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Comment: I've tried that but I think the porblme is other, which I described in the original post.